# File Download Using Spring Boot and MSSQL

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot, download

I am working on uploading and downloading files using Spring Boot, JSP and MSSQL. I am able to run the upload and download function, BUT the file that I downloaded from the database is **corrupted**. Can anyone help me with this?

this is my spring version

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity < Object > upload(@RequestPart(required = false) MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    try {
        if (file != null) {
            tmDAO.storeFile(file, tm);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity < Object > ("success", HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@RequestMapping("/downloadFile/{id}")
public String downloadFile(@PathVariable("id") String id,
    HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
    FileModel fm = tmDAO.getFile(id);
    try {
        File file = new File(fm.getName());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        res.setContentLength(fm.getData().length);
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fm.getName());
        fos.write(fm.getData(), 0, fm.getData().length);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return "string";
}
```

Service

```
    
@Override
public FileModel storeFile(MultipartFile file, TeachingMaterial tm) throws IOException {
    String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
    FileModel fileModel = new FileModel(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), tm.getContributor(), fileName,
    file.getContentType(), file.getBytes(), tm.getClassName(), tm.getSubjectName(), tm.getSlots());
    return fileRepo.save(fileModel);
}

@Override
public FileModel getFile(String id) throws IOException {
    Optional < FileModel > fm = fileRepo.findById(id);
    if (fm.isPresent()) {
        return fm.get();
    }
    return null;
}
```

FileModel.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FILES")
public class FileModel {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String contributor;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    @Lob
    private byte[] data;
    private String className;
    private String subjectName;
    private String slots;

    public FileModel() {
        super();
    }

    public FileModel(String id, String contributor, String name, String type, byte[] data, String className,
            String subjectName, String slots) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.contributor = contributor;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.data = data;
        this.className = className;
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
        this.slots = slots;
    }
**I skips the getters and setters for simplication**
}
```

Record in MSSQL

[image]

what I get after downloading the txt file

[image]

the original data should be

testing123

abc

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: *the file that I downloaded from the database is corrupted* - is it corrupted in the DB, or only when downloaded using your code?

Comment: when downloaded using code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem could be related to the way you are performing the file download:

```java
@RequestMapping("/downloadFile/{id}")
public String downloadFile(@PathVariable("id") String id,
    HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
    FileModel fm = tmDAO.getFile(id);
    try {
        File file = new File(fm.getName());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        res.setContentLength(fm.getData().length);
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fm.getName());
        fos.write(fm.getData(), 0, fm.getData().length);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return "string";
}
```

Note in your code that you are writing the obtained `FileModel` data to a `FileOutputStream`, but you should write that data to the `HttpServletResponse` underlying `OutputStream` instead. Please, consider the following modification in your code:

```java
@RequestMapping("/downloadFile/{id}")
public void downloadFile(
    @PathVariable("id") String id,
    HttpServletResponse res
) throws IOException {
    // Define an auxiliary InputStream: more on this later
    InputStream in = null;
    // Define a reference to the response OutputStream. We will initialize
    // it later
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        FileModel fm = tmDAO.getFile(id);
        byte[] data = fm.getData();
        // initialize the response content-type (perhaps with type?)
        // and additional headers
        res.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        res.setContentLength(data.length);
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 
             "attachment; filename=" + fm.getName());
        
        // write data to output

        // This variable ideally should be defined as a constant
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        out = res.getOutputStream();

        while(data.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        }

        out.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        // cleanup
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close(); 
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close(); 
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // there is no need to return anything
}
```

If you wish, this process could be greatly simplified using the handly [IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) class from the [Apache Commons IO project](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.11.0):

```java
@RequestMapping("/downloadFile/{id}")
public void downloadFile(
    @PathVariable("id") String id,
    HttpServletResponse res
) throws IOException {
    // Define a reference to the response OutputStream. We will initialize
    // it later
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        FileModel fm = tmDAO.getFile(id);
        byte[] data = fm.getData();
        // initialize the response content-type (perhaps with type?)
        // and additional headers
        res.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        res.setContentLength(data.length);
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 
             "attachment; filename=" + fm.getName());
        
        // write data to output
        
        out = res.getOutputStream();

        // As suggested by @Olivier in this comments, we can
        // get rid of the ByteArrayInputStream and use data directly
        IOUtils.copy(data, out);

        out.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        // cleanup
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
    }

    // there is no need to return anything
}
```

Spring provides additional methods for dealing with writing `byte[]` to the wire but your solution is a simple and very good one.

Comment: Why don't you write `data` directly to the output? Why use a `ByteArrayInputStream`?

Comment: And I don't think you need to call `close()` on the output stream. The servlet container does it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @Olivier. I copied and pasted from the original code, but yes, I absolutely agree with you. Regarding whether to close or not the `ServletOutputStream`, I prefer to always close it explicitly to prevent any possible problem, although again I agree with you, the spec indicates that the servlet container  has that responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

Below is how your `downloadFile` method should look like (since you are loading blob contents into memory there is nothing to optimize out)

```java
@RequestMapping("/downloadFile/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> downloadFile(@PathVariable("id") String id) throws IOException {
    FileModel fm = tmDAO.getFile(id);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.builder("attachment")
      .filename(fm.getName(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
      .build());
    headers.setContentLength(fm.getData().length);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ByteArrayResource(fm.getData()), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping("/download")
public void download(String path, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String filePath = fielUrl + "\\" + path;
    File file = new File(filePath);

    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    String filename = new File(filePath).getName();
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");

    response.addHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8"));

    ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int len;
   
    while ((len = inputStream.read(b)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(b, 0, len);
    }
    inputStream.close();
}
```

You can refer to my code.
Pay attention to setting the "response".